# Deixar selecionada uma option específica quando usar um select

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-select

Estou gerando um select passando algumas opçoes como mostra o código abaixo

```
select name="listing_search[realty_types][]"
  - Realty.translated_realty_types.each do |k, v|
    option value="#{v}" #{k}
```

Como faço para deixar selecionado a segunda opção da lista? Eu sei que existe o SELECTED, mas não estou sabendo usar ai.

Answer (score 1):

```
  - Realty.translated_realty_types.each_with_index do |k, v, index|
    - if index == 0
      option selected value="#{v}" #{k} 
    - else
      option value="#{v}" #{k}
```

Comment: Obrigado, eu modifiquei umas coisas e foi!